# Slight play in trackpad on 2014 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

The trackpad on my 15" 2014 Macbook Pro has some play.

When hovering with two fingers - say, when not scrolling in a page, but ready to - I can feel it shift 1-2mm vertically. Not enough for a "click," but enough so that it's distracting.

(Yes, I realize how annoying it must be to hear someone complain about 1-2mm, but I use this thing 12 hours a day and it's freaking annoying. Also, it's a $3700+ machine, so I expect as close to perfection as possible.)

Suggestions? This is my second Retina model (fifth counting warranty replacements) and the first time I've noticed this particular problem.

Has anyone else seen this? Is it expected wear-and-tear (I've had this machine for a few months now)? I know if I take it in to the Apple store and they agree that there is a problem, it'll be a top case replacement. They typically keep the same SSD sticks when they do that, but I still back everything up, which takes some time, as does the restore, and I'm not looking forward to (once again) being without my machine for a week. I can't do my job without this thing, and usually wind up buying $$$ another one to use while it's out. Which is not fun.

Comment: It is not annoying to complain about a defect, regardless of how small it may seem! With that said, I'd bring it into Apple and have them check it out. It is definitely inconvenient to be without the machine for a while, but its better than living with the defect for the rest of the machine's life.

Comment: There's a triwing screw on the underside of the trackpad that lets you adjust the trackpad's clickiness, but I'm not sure about how easily accessible it is on a rMBP

Comment: do you have extremely dry hands and sit on a electrically isolated surface (carpet or linoleum or wood floor)